# Laravel GraphiQL "documentation explorer" says "no schema available"

Tags: php, laravel, graphql, documentation, graphiql

I'm using this Laravel graphQL implementation : https://github.com/rebing/graphql-laravel, which uses this graphiQL implementation : https://github.com/graphql/graphiql

I'm trying to explore my graphQL schema using graphiQL through `https://my_IP/graphiql` route, but it just says `NO SCHEMA AVAILABLE` as follow:

[image]

However, it should display documentation like here : https://graphql.org/swapi-graphql

I have schema declaration in `config/graphql.php` as follow:

```
'schemas' => [
        'default' => [
            'query' => [
                'users' => \myPath\UsersQuery::class,
                'subscribers' => \myPath\SubscribersQuery::class,
                ...
            ],
            'mutation' => [
                ...
            ],
            'middleware' => [],
            'method' => ['get', 'post'],
        ],
    ],
```

Did I miss some configuration to allow the documentation exploration ?

Comment: fixed the issue. In my case, there was a middleware security check I had to hack to allow the request from `https://my_IP/graphiql`